# Code behaving differently in console and in content script on youtube.com

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to remove an element from youtube.com using a chrome extension. The content script runs (it can log data to the console) but doesn't remove the element. However, if I copy the code for the content script into the developer mode console, it changes the page as expected. This problem doesn't occur when trying to change the DOM on other sites using a content script. Modifying other elements in the page such as removing the entire body works.
I use setTimeout to make sure the page has loaded. (I know there are better ways, but I wanted a quick mock of the problem)

```
elem = document.getElementById("items")
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem)
```

These two lines remove the recommended videos, but only when pasted to the console.

Manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": ["tabs","storage","declarativeContent","*://*.youtube.com/*"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["*://*.youtube.com/*"],
        "js": ["youtubeDomChange.js"]
    }
  ],
}
```

youtubeDomChange.js:

```
setTimeout(function(){

    console.log("ran")
    elem = document.getElementById("items")
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem)

},6000);
```

**Edit 1:** `console.log(element.parentNode)` does return different output from the content script and manually pasting the code into the console. No errors are raised.
[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdKlI.png)

Comment: Is it getting any error? What does `console.log(elem.parentNode)` show?

Comment: YouTube is a modern site that renders itself programmatically. See [How to detect page navigation on Youtube and modify HTML before page is rendered?](//stackoverflow.com/q/34077641)/